# findOneAndUpdate (mongoose) returns true for updating a nested document in a model but nothing is updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Yes, I know there are very similar other questions and I was looking at them, but, unfortunately, I could not find a solution. So, I am trying to update a nested document in a mongoose model with "findOneAndUpdate" method but even though it is returning a document, this one is the original one, not the updated.

Below is the model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var teamMemberModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "_id": mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    "email": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 20
    },
    "name": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 20
    },
    "role": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
    "twitter": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
    "facebook": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
    "linkedin": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 20,
        "max": 50
    },
});

var teamModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "title": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 20
    },
    "headline": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 30
    },
    "description": {
        "type": String,
        "required": true,
        "min": 5,
        "max": 80
    },
    "members": [teamMemberModelSchema]
}, { collection: 'team' });

teamModelSchema.set('collection', 'team');
mongoose.model('team', teamModelSchema);
```

I want to update a member nested document with this following code snippet:

```
module.exports.teamMemberUpdate = function (req, res) {

    var email = req.body.email;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var role = req.body.role;
    var twitter = req.body.twitter;
    var facebook = req.body.facebook;
    var linkedin = req.body.linkedin;

    teamFunctions.findTeamMember(email)
        .then(data => {

            if (data.length === 0) {
                responseUtilities.sendJSON(res, false, { "message": teamMsg.teamMemberNotFound });
            }
            else {
                return data[0];
            }

        })
        .then(() => {

            const query = { "members.email": email };
            const options = { new: true };
            var update = {
                $set: {
                    email: email,
                    name: name,
                    role: role,
                    twitter: twitter,
                    facebook: facebook,
                    linkedin: linkedin
                }
            };

            TeamModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (err, result) {
                var message = teamMsg.teamMemberUpdatedSuccess;
                if (!result) {
                    message = teamMsg.teamMemberUpdatedError;
                }
                responseUtilities.sendJSON(res, err, { "message": message });
            });

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
            responseUtilities.sendJSON(res, err, { "message": err.message });
        });
}
```

"teamMemberUpdatedSuccess" value is displayed, but in fact, the original document is not updated.

Can anyone find out where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the positional $ operator with dot notation. [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) is the docs for your scenario.

You can use the following function to update a member with a given email. As you see we have only one db access. There is no need to use `teamFunctions.findTeamMember` function.

I used some modern javascript features like [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)  and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) syntax for clean code.

```js
module.exports.teamMemberUpdate = async function(req, res) {
  const { email, name, role, twitter, facebook, linkedin } = req.body;

  const query = {
    "members.email": email
  };

  const options = { new: true };
  const update = {
    $set: {
      "members.$.email": email,
      "members.$.name": name,
      "members.$.role": role,
      "members.$.twitter": twitter,
      "members.$.facebook": facebook,
      "members.$.linkedin": linkedin
    }
  };

  try {
    const result = await TeamModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);

    if (!result) {
      return res.status(400).send("No member found for the email");
    }
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
};
```

Please first try with this function without changing anything, after you see it works, you may make application specific changes.

Also I noticed a minor probem in your schema definition, you should use `minlenght` and `maxlength` options for String type instead of `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 0):

`TeamModel` does not have any property called `email`, `name` etc (see your update variable). Your update query should look like this:

```
const update = {
  $set: {
    'members.$.email': email
  }
};
```

That `$` is important because `members` is an array.

Hope it helps.